# Dual Boot: "Invalid partition table" & cannot boot into Windows 10 anymore

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub, arch-linux, mbr

I recently re-did my system setup, having two separate SSDs because Windows usually tries to screw Linux installations up if it's on the same physical disk.

**HDD layout**

```
HDD0 | nvme0n1 | Samsung SSD 970 PRO 512GB | Antergos 19.4 (LUKS)
HDD1 | sda     | Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB | Windows 10 (non-BitLocker)
```

**Problem**

My problem is, that I cannot boot into Windows anymore (selecting the Windows Boot Manager from the boot selection screen defaults to the Antergos GRUB) and I cannot see HDD1 in the BIOS anymore to choose an `.efi` file to set as a secure boot option ("Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing").

Additionally, Windows Boot Manager points to the wrong HDD (in boot selection: "Windows Boot Manager (Samsung SSD 970 PRO 512GB)") - or at least I think so, I did not pay attention to this when I set up the Windows system initially...

Here's what I did so far:

**Windows Installation**

First, I installed and configured Windows on HDD1 with default partitioning etc. All went well, several reboots & update-cycles later I was still able to boot into the Windows partition.

**Arch/Antergos Installation**

Then I installed Antergos (hence the `arch-linux` tag, I hope that's ok. 19.4 ISO, if that even matters) on HDD0/nvme0n1, LUKS-encrypted, with GRUB also on nvme0n1. However, there seems to be a known problem with Antergos installs, which I fixed by following a [blog post describing a near-identical issue](https://bitoverlay.com/how-to-fix-grub-efi-boot-on-antergos/) with the following steps to fix the boot issue:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 luks
vgscan
vgchange -ay
lvscan
mount /dev/mapper/AntergosVG-AntergosRoot /mnt/
mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot/
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
arch-chroot /mnt/
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=Antergos-grub
reboot now
```

And in the BIOS, I added the `HDD0/Antergos-grub/...../something.efi` to boot from.

After this, I was able to boot into Antergos but somewhere along the way I apparently screwed up my Windows boot settings.

**Trying To Boot Into Windows**

As mentioned above, Windows Boot Manager fails and the system then defaults to Antergos' GRUB.

A quick `file -sL /dev/sda*` showed an "Invalid partition table" on `/dev/sda` which I tried to fix with `dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/bios/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda`.

This seemed to fix the "Invalid partition table", as it is now reported as follows:

```
/dev/sda:  DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x3ff,255,63), startsector 1, 4294967295 sectors
/dev/sda1: data
/dev/sda2: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 34816, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS, sectors/track 63, sectors 974999354, $MFT start cluster 786432, $MFTMirror start cluster 2, bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246), clusters/index block 1, serial number XXXXXXXXXX
/dev/sda3: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 975034368, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS, sectors/track 63, sectors 1736703, $MFT start cluster 72362, $MFTMirror start cluster 2, bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246), clusters/index block 1, serial number XXXXXXXXXY
```

However, the initial problem still persists. I still cannot boot into Windows, nor can I see the HDD0 in the BIOS to select a `.efi`. On the plus side: I can access the Windows data partition (`/dev/sda2`) from within Antergos without any problems.

**Is there a way to fix this or can someone at least pinpoint the part I messed up?**

BTW: `os-prober` does not return *any* values (`ntfs-3g` is installed)

---

**`fdisk -l`**

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 PRO 512GB               
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0F772FB5-4DA6-446D-8F16-4DBFBA125765

Device           Start        End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624    2099199   1048576  512M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 2099200 1000214527 998115328  476G Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DA0363ED-80AB-4644-8238-E84A34DB7B8B

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048     34815     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2      34816 975034170 974999355 464,9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  975034368 976771071   1736704   848M Windows recovery environment
```

**Missing Windows "fix" including output**

*(as described in the linked blog post above)*

```
$ sudo su
# os-prober
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/Antergos-Default/theme.txt
Found Intel Microcode image
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initramfs image: /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux-lts.img
Found fallback initramfs image: /boot/initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img
done
# grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=Antergos-grub
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

**Available (non-Antergos) `.efi` Files on HDD0**

```
HDD0/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi/grubx64.efi
HDD0/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi/grubx64.efi
```

BTW: adding any of those `.efi` leads to an `FILE is exist` (sic!) error anyway...

Comment: Apparently you installed one OS in UEFI mode and the other in Legacy (Windows). Grub (UEFI) can't work for the purpose of booting a Legacy Windows. So, I think that due to a lack of understanding of UEFI you ended up complicating things a lot and not having a proper dual boot system.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia yes, that sounds like something I might do... But why does this lead to HDD1 disappearing from the BIOS? And why does this affect anything at all if I'm trying to boot from a completely different HDD without GRUB?

Comment: You have UEFI, not BIOS, and this is an important distinction. You may continue referring to the firmware as "BIOS" like many people and manufacturers still do, but it's important to understand that "UEFI mode" is always preferable as long as the OSes support it (Windows and AntergOS do) and that it boots differently than an old BIOS system (Legacy): It uses GPT drives, not MBR, and all the bootloaders are installed in a small EFI partition (again, GPT has no Master Boot Record), regardless of the location of the OS(es) system partition(s). Implications >(next)

Comment: > Unlike before, different bootloaders can coexist in the EFI partition and be selected independently from the firmware and the boot process isn't chosen from one drive or the other (or more...). The drive boot order is merely to select the drive that contains the EFI partition. From there, in a different setting, users choose the the boot order of the OSes which is read from that small partition by the firmware but other than that it has nothing to do with the drive where the chosen OS is installed. Any system needs only one EFI partition.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - Ok, thanks for the excellent explanation! I did not pay attention to this initially because I wanted to keep the two installations as separate as possible. So to fix this issue I have to: 0. Wipe everything 1. Make sure that the Win10 USB is GPT/UEFI 2. Install Win10 on HDD0 3. Install Antergos with manual partitioning on HDD1 and use Windows' EFI partition to mount it to /boot/efi in Antergos 4. Enjoy..... Is this correct or am I still missing something?

Comment: Yes, it's a good approximation :) With the Windows Media Creation tool the resulting USB stick will boot in either mode. What you select to boot from is then crucial. I always disable Legacy/CSM to avoid mistakes. The default is usually both modes in which case the USB is listed twice, one with "UEFI", the other without (disabling CSM enables the correct UEFI mode only). And the EFI partition isn't Windows', it's for all and any OS you decide to install. That partition is also created by any modern Linux installer when installing Linux only to a blank drive.

Comment: In the end you want to select "Antergos" as the boot priority the same way as with BIOS. It boots Grub that should give you the familiar menu including Windows(it chainloads back to the Windows bootloader EFI file). This is the great advantage of UEFI mode for multi-boot: Any OS can be booted independently from the firmware. If anything happens to the Linux that won't be a "tragedy" as before because you'll be able to still boot Windows directly whereas before you'd need to boot Windows installation media to "fix MBR" (reinstalling Windows bootloader in the MBR).

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase: "The EFI partition first created by Windows" :) Fantastic! Since I can't really use the WMC tool without Windows, I have to do it via my current Antergos installation. From what I understood, it should be enough to reformat the USB drive with GPT and a FAT32 partition, and then simply copy everything from the ISO. Could you please combine your comments into an answer, so I can accept it (given that everything works out fine :) )?

Comment: Redid the setup as advised by @GabrielaGarcia - works like a charm (had to add the Antergos .efi file manually). Grub detects antergos and windows, everything seems to be in order. Thanks a ton!